# How to return an object in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to return an object of class User in laravel 5.2 but all I get is 'Undefined variable: user' and I am sure that I am logged and there is an instance of the User. The code is:

```
$name = 'Random';
$this->createCustomer($name);

dd($user);

public function createCustomer($name) {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user ->name = $name;
    $user ->save();

    return $user;
}
```

All I get at the end is 'Undefined variable: user'

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Please be more clear about where you're using the functions and where you're `dd($user)` occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createCustomer` creates the object and returns it, which you then need to assign. Otherwise, it does not exist outside of its function. You can read more about [variable scope here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

```
$user = $this->createCustomer($name);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I new that I am missing something too obvious.